# Windows 10 1803 Build 17134.48 does not load NVIDIA Device Drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1803

Windows 10 ver 1083 build 17134.48 does not recognize either the GTX-560 or GT-630 graphics adapters. Installation of any driver version for these cards fails. Microsoft tech support unable to fix at level 1 support. Level 2 support will contact in 2 weeks. I have no confidence. NVIDIA customer support is as useful as Microsoft's.

On startup the manufacturer's banner flashes on-screen. When attempting to load the appropriate driver, both from Device Manager and the NVIDIA installation program the loading process terminates with an uninformitave "an error has occurred". The problem is with this specific build of Windows.

These drivers have worked in previous versions of Windows 10
I have tried 2 different cards. 
I have updated all my drivers (wasted $40).
Rolling back to a previous version is not realistic since this build took over 12 hours to complete.

Comment: How did you spend money on drivers?

Comment: Edit your question to include which version of the Nvidia driver you are attempting to install.  Additionally, if you let Windows Update install the drivers, is it able to install the driver?  Do you have both cards installed or just one?  Please clarify your question by editing it

Comment: The problem is fixed. See https://superuser.com/questions/1092694/nvidia-driver-install-fails

Comment: Yes, a possible duplicate. However this is a specific problem with build 17134.48 for which there was no other reference.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say you "wasted $40" updating your drivers? Did you purchase a third-party application that promised to update your drivers? If so, there is a VERY good change you paid for scamware or malware and your computer is now not to be trusted and should be fully reimaged. There is NEVER any need to pay to update drivers. OEMs publish drivers on their websites where you can find and download them. This is the only way you should ever get drivers.

Comment: I am well aware that "free" driver update software has the potential for trashing my system, which was the reason I had no problem buying the AVG product. Most of the system board drivers were out of date (as of 2006) and the drivers loaded by the AVG update product pulled most of the from Intel and other OEM sites were later versions that those provided by Microsoft. I have a Dell Inspiron 580, which Dell no longer supports.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to previous questions: Build 17134.48 set the display adapter to Microsoft VGA default. Spent $40 on AVG Driver Updater. Don't trust "free".

The problem is fixed. See [NVIDIA Driver Install Fails](https://superuser.com/questions/1092694/nvidia-driver-install-fails) and http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html.

1. Downloaded app.
2. Ran msconfig for "safe boot".
3. Rebooted.
4. Ran msconfig for "normal boot".
5. Ran app with recommended setting.
6. Rebooted.
7. Ran NVIDIA installation app.

Everything works the way its supposed to.

Now to tell Microsoft and NVIDIA how to fix their problem.